# How can i do the following functionality using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

This is  angularjs map and a textbox creation code..
The thing i need is, when user enters a place in textbox and after pressing enter that place should indicate in the map....
please help me with this...
thanks in advance...

```html
<html ng-app="angular-google-maps-example">

    

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>angular-google-maps example</title>
 <style>
 .angular-google-map {
   display: block;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <google-map
  center="centerProperty"
  zoom="zoomProperty" 
  markers="markersProperty"
  latitude="clickedLatitudeProperty"
  longitude="clickedLongitudeProperty"
  mark-click="true"
  draggable="true"
  style="height: 450px; width: 100%">
 </google-map>

  <br>
  
  <textarea name="" class="eventDesc" id="" rows="5" placeholder="Full Address" ng-model="event.address"></textarea>
  
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/application/html/js/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
 
  
  
  <script>
 var module = angular.module("angular-google-maps-example", ["google-maps"]);
 function ExampleController ($scope) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
   centerProperty: {
    lat: 45,
    lng: -73
   },
          
   zoomProperty: 8,
          
   markersProperty: [ {
     latitude: 45,
     longitude: -74
    }],
   clickedLatitudeProperty: null, 
   clickedLongitudeProperty: null,
  });
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular app isn't setup correctly, you need to register the controller to your angular app before you can use it in ng-controller.

```js
var module = angular.module("angular-google-maps-example", ["google-maps"]);

module.controller('ExampleController', function ExampleController ($scope) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    centerProperty: {
      lat: 45,
      lng: -73
    },

    zoomProperty: 8,

    markersProperty: [ {
      latitude: 45,
      longitude: -74
    }],
    clickedLatitudeProperty: null, 
    clickedLongitudeProperty: null,
  });
});
```